# iPython won't start anymore after using os.dup2()

Tags: crash, ipython

I was just trying out the os.dup2() function to redirect outputs, when I was typing in os.dup2(3,1), which my ipython (2.7) didn't seem to like.
It crashed and now it won't start again, yielding the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 8, in <module>
    launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 402, in launch_new_instance
    app.initialize()
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 84, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 312, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/ipapp.py", line 332, in init_shell
    ipython_dir=self.ipython_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 318, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 183, in __init__
user_module=user_module, custom_exceptions=custom_exceptions
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1777, in init_readline
    self.refill_readline_hist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1789, in refill_readline_hist
    include_latest=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 256, in get_tail
    return reversed(list(cur))
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

can anyone help me with that?

Comment: That looks like fd 3 is your IPython history database, and you redirected stdout to it and corrupted it. To get it to start again, remove or rename `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite`

Comment: thanks for the respond!
i can't find that file on my system... well, I tried reinstalling ipython since (which should have removed it, right?) but it's still not starting... python itself works just as normal, though.
any other suggestions?

Comment: If you have certain versions of IPython, it might be located at `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

That looks like fd 3 is your IPython history database, and you redirected stdout to it and corrupted it.

To get it to start again, remove or rename `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` (or `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` on certain IPython versions on Linux).